# Shopify - SSL API CALLS do not work from http://

Tags: json, getjson, shopify

I try to do some AJAX-magic on the landing-page of my shopify-shop using the Shopify AJAX API.
But for calling the Shopify AJAX API I have to use SSL, doing something like this:

```
$.getJSON("https://API-KEY:PASSWORD@myDomain.myshopify.com/admin/products.json?collection_id=9947999";, function(data) {...
```

That means I'm coming from HTTP (http://myDomain.net) using HTTPS (https://API-KEY:PASSWORD@myDomain.myshopify.com) in the AJAX-call, which does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hi Tobi,`

this is a really bad idea. You should not be revealing your API-KEY & PASSWORD, which is exactly what you will be doing here. It would let someone malicious mess with all aspects of your shop.

One option that might work for you is to set up a script on a server you control to hit from your shop using JSONP.

You can find info on the what api they do offer for ajax here: http://wiki.shopify.com/Ajax_API

Comment: Thanks for your valuable hint! You saved me!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you control your server, you can even do away with JSONP and setup the more modern and slick CORS. Works like a peach for me, although older IE browsers can choke.